# I'm having an `argument of type` warning while using memset

Tags: c, arrays, memset

I have the array;

`volatile uint32_t SoftTimers[8] ;`

I want to reset my arrays all content to zero in the program(not initialization). I searched for this and found `memset`. But im having this warning(not error) while using this function, is that a problem?

I used `memset` like this:

memset(SoftTimers, 0, sizeof(SoftTimers));

And this is the warning message:

> warning:  #167-D: argument of type "volatile uint32_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use memset in this case, because it takes a non-volatile pointer, while you are trying to pass a volatile pointer:

> 6.7.3 Type qualifiers
>
> 6. If an attempt is
>    made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
>    with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

Write your own function, that takes a pointer to `volatile uint32_t` type.

Comment: I understand, so is there a faster way than for loop to do this operations?

Comment: I was gonna use this `memset` function at an interrupt handler. So i dont want to spend much time at there. I was trying to be efficient

Comment: @abdullahcinar Make sure the code is correct first. You can worry about speed later.

Comment: It was correct while i'm using for loop reset. I just wanted to spend less time. But you're right, important thing is its working correct. Thanks for the reply :)